# Copy a file from SFTP to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3

I am trying to copy a file from SFTP to S3.
I don't want to land the file intermediate server please suggest me ways to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't have access to/control of the sftp server. If you do have access, it's easy.

Otherwise, pick the language of your choice and stream the data. For instance, with Python you can use [paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko)'s `sftp.getfo()` and point that file stream at Boto's `s3.key.send_file()`. That keeps you from needing to download the file to disk.

However, there's no way to tell a random SFTP server to send it to S3.

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes i am using python paramiko's module. Currently the way i am doing this, i copying the file first to edge node and then moving to s3, if you have any example thats greatly appreciated

Comment: @sundeepveeramachaneni, I've given you pointers to the code. That should be enough for to at least attempt to write the code yourself.